# Creación de un PDF desde Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, stream

Dispongo de un inputStream con la información contenida en un PDF(viene desde base de datos), y necesito enviar por correo un pdf generado a partir de eso.

La parte del envío está solucionada, el problema es crear el PDF(y que no esté corrupto).Alguna manera de creación de un pdf desde un inputStream, ya sea de un objeto de la clase PdfDocument o Document?

Uso IText 5 debido a mi versión de java(no puedo usar otra versión en este programa).

He intentado varias maneras pero no lo consigo. No tendría problema en usar otras librerías de eso permitirme crear el PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesaria una librería para la creación de PDF si se dispone de un inputStream.

Un PDF, al ser un archivo de datos, no de texto, no puede leerse ni escribirse como una cadena, ya que se pierde información,recomiendo utilizar IOUtils, del paquete Apache Commons IO, concretamente su método toByteArray(InputStream).

Una vez obtenido el byte[] correctamente, podemos escribirlo en otro fichero con extensión ".pdf".

```
File file=new File("nuevoPDF.pdf");
InputStream stream=dto.getContenido();//de aquí saco el inputStream del que hablo
OutputStream salida=new FileOutputStream(file);

byte[] array=IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
salida.write(array);
salida.close();
stream.close();
```

Nunca hay que olvidar cerrar los flujos.

Comment: Respondo a mi propia pregunta ya que he visto muchísimas veces en la versión en inglés esta pregunta y no he encontrado respuesta sin utilizar librerías.

Comment: Con lo que agregas puedes crear un archivo, del mismo modo como creas un archivo de cualquier extensión, pero ¿como agregarías información a este archivo .PDF?, de otra forma este solo sería un .pdf sin contenido; en el caso de iText te permite precisamente esto.

Comment: @Jorgesys Ya especifico que la información viene en el inputStream desde base de datos, sería leer un BLOB, y a partir del flujo, si lo escribes como cadena de bytes en otro fichero y le das la extensión, copia la información de uno a otro, incluyendo colores, imágenes y demás.

Comment: @Jorgesys Sería más simple con el IText u otras librerías, pero quise ayudar a los que por X motivo no puedan usar una librería, como fue mi caso.